# Bootstrap 4 navbar item jumps below and wraps

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a navbar with latest bootstrap4 (alpha6). 
[image]

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
   <img src="/public/img/logo.png" height="36" alt="myLogo">
   <span class="navbar-text">Food on Track</span>
</a>
<ul class="ml-auto nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <svg fill="currentColor" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="1em" width="1em" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <g><path d="..."></path></g>
        </svg>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to make nav brand and items fit one line using bootstrap 4?
Here's a link to [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/kA92EPqLPB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs for the navbar](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/).

Use `navbar-nav` instead of `nav` and a `navbar-toggleable-*` class to keep the nav horizontal until a specific breakpoint when it will collapse vertically.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-toggleable-md">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/public/img/logo.png" height="36" alt="myLogo">
         Food on Track
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <svg>
            </svg>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/iAGnRLMCE1

**Update 2018**

In Bootstrap 4.0.0 `navbar-toggleable-*` has been changed to `navbar-expand-*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
   <img src="/public/img/logo.png" height="36" alt="myLogo">
   <span class="navbar-text">Food on Track</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<ul class="ml-auto nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <svg fill="currentColor" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="1em" width="1em" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <g><path d="..."></path></g>
        </svg>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well it's an interesting decision, but I believe there must be more elegent way then to use grid

Comment: it worked for me, there could be other methods i know not of.

Comment: I guess someone would come up with a better solution and I could learn from it